# How to change parent view variable from "nilb cell"?

Tags: swift, cell

Everyone:

I have a simple collectionview, and registered a nib cell.

What I want is : after textField value was changed, pass the value to parent viewController variable.

I found some sugesstion for viewcontroller to viewcontroller, not what I want. Sorry, I just code with SWIFT.....

Hear is my code:

// ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let cellid = "cellid"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cv: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        cv.dataSource = self
        
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell",bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellid)

    }
}
```

/// Nib Cell Class

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblText: UITextField!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        lblText.delegate = self
        
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        // Make a input text check here and pass data to ViewController for save these data that user input!
        .....
        return true

    }

}
```

Comment: hi, can you share your code?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I went to have meal

Comment: Model View Controller. You change _data_ (model), not a "view's variable". Views do not store information. They are _interface_.

Comment: Yes, Matt! But I have to let main ViewController "aware" some data is changed!